# Smooth CSS rotate animation on hover

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I've create a button, and I want it to rotate 360deg on mouse hover, and rotate backwords 360deg on hover off. So far it work well, but if you go slowly towards it with the mouse, it flickers.

Here's the short version of the code:

```css
.btn {
 display: block;
 margin: 60px auto;
 width: 250px;
 padding: 15px; 
 position: relative; 

 color: #3498db;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
   
 border: 5px solid #3498db;
     
 transform: rotate(360deg);
 transition: all 0.5s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.8, 0.5, 1);
}

.btn-rotate:hover {
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 transition-delay: 0;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-rotate">I am a button!</a>
```

for full code, check the codpen demo http://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/ojBNZx

Comment: That's because when you rotate it, you aren't hovering any more,

Comment: If you want the button to do the full animation once its hovered you need to use jQuery (or pure Javascript) - if thats an option - tell us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea where it adds an extra pseudo element only when you're hovering :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyWJoZ?editors=110)

```
.btn:after {
  content: '';
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btn:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

Gave it a bit of background color, just so it's better visible what's going on...

For the most control, I'd resort to some JavaScript though.

Answer (score 2):

The flicker issue is happening because, when you hover on the element, the elements start to rotate. After rotating some x degree, the element would've **rotated to certain degree and the mouse/cursor is not anymore on the element**.
This is the reason the flicker is happening.

Comparing to the above one, I feel using wrapper (div) and analyzed how much width we may need, we set that to div. On div:hover element, we can perform the transition. It gives better result compared to now.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dttvhcLo/1/)

```
.buttonHolder {
    padding: 50px;  
}

.buttonHolder:hover .btn-rotate {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition-delay: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
```